# create a graph for each row in data frame

Tags: dataframe, plot, graph, pyspark

Suppose I have this dataframe :

```
country  |  co_1 | col_2 |col_3 |col_4 |
US          5       6      3      2  
RU          3       2      1      7
IND         6       6      5       2
.
.
.
etc .................
```

Country values are unique of course i have distinct countries and i want for each country to plot a graph of the values in that row.  For example for US we would have a graph going from 5 to 6 to 3 to 2. Preferably in the same table/graph to plot also RU values .

In the end i want number of graphs plotted to be equal to number of rows=number of countries that i have.  Preferably all in the same table so i can compare all the graphs of countries plotted. Is there a way to do it from a Dataframe?  Or looping through it and converting each row to list?  Which looks like bad performance if i Have plenty of rows

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you want to graph this as a line chart, you could select the column with a static value and union them so you have a row with each value. If you are in databricks you should then be able to plot with the countries as labels.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you not understand? Maybe its because  my dataframe  isnt edited well here. I dont know  how to edit it to stand normally.  Anyways.. yes I want line graph for each. What do you mean a row to have all values? Each row ineed does have all values

Comment: Also I dont see label option in databricks. I just have value key and series